# Behavior of the tails of symmetric sample means

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider a continuous distribution $\mathcal{D}$ symmetric around mean $\mu$ and with finite variance and cumulative distribution function $F$, and consider the sample means $S_{n_1}, S_{n_2}$ corresponding respectively to $n_1<n_2$ IID draws from $\mathcal{D}$. Since $\mathcal{D}$ it is symmetric and continuous, so are $S_{n_1}$ and $S_{n_2}$.

Let $F_{S_{n_1}}$ and $F_{S_{n_2}}$ be their cumulative distribution functions, and let $\epsilon>0$ be such that $F(\mu+\epsilon)<1$; this also implies that $F_{S_{n_1}}(\mu+\epsilon), F_{S_{n_2}}(\mu+\epsilon)<1$.

Enough foreplay. [image: tail CDFs]

I think that $1-F_{S_{n_1}}(\mu+\epsilon)>1-F_{S_{n_2}}(\mu+\epsilon)$ – that is, that the tails of the sample distributions shrink as the sample size increases. Is this true?

At first, I thought it was true because just the sample means are symmetric and their variance is inversely related to sample size: $\mathbb{V}(S_{n_1})=\frac{\mathbb{V}(\mathcal{D})}{n_1}>\frac{\mathbb{V}(\mathcal{D})}{n_2}=\mathbb{V}(S_{n_2})$. But that's not quite right, it's not enough for the two distributions to just have equal mean, symmetry, and decreased variance. Consider the following counterexample:

> On the interval $[0, 10]$, the distribution that puts $0.5$ on $2$ and $0.5$ on $8$ has higher variance than one which puts $0.1$ on $0$, $0.8$ on 5, and $0.1$ on 10, but if you choose $\epsilon = 4$, the claim doesn't hold.

Now, this counterexample doesn't satisfy some of our assumptions (like continuity or $F_{S_{n_1}}(\mu+\epsilon), F_{S_{n_2}}(\mu+\epsilon)<1$), but that's not important, because we could repair the counterargument with a little more complication.

So, what's going on here? If this is true, is because of an additional property that the sample distributions have. I've been told this has something to do with "the concavity of the convolution of the density functions with tail integral", or something.

EDIT: A friend writes,

> For a simple counter-example, consider a symmetric distribution $\mathcal{D}$ with the following properties: $P(|\mathcal{D}|<1)=2/3, P(|\mathcal{D}|>100)=1/3$.
>
> Then if we set $ε = 2$, for example, $n_1=1$ and $n_2=2$, then $P(S_{n_1}>2)=\frac{1}{6}$ and $P(S_{n_2>2})=1-(\frac{5}{6})^2=\frac{11}{36}$, which is larger.

Is there a regularity condition which excludes this kind of thing? Perhaps if the graph of the PDF were convex? In particular, I'm most confident this is true for $\mathcal{D}$ uniform, so maybe that's the easiest case to consider.